# Using a helper function in the config/session.php gives an error with all php artisan commands / composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

In the session.php I use the helper function url() for creating a dynamic domain name. This way when I move to the real server I won't have to change the domain name. It looks like this:

```
'domain' => url(''),
```

Everything works fine in the browser but when I use any php artisan or composer commands from the terminal it will give me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738
```

Trying it like this doesn't seem to help

```
'domain' => @url(''),
```

Is there anything to be done?
I'm using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the [`url`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L721-L738) helper function uses the [`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php) class to generate the URL and that class requires a `Request` instance to be injected. And in your particular case the problem there is no request context for an artisan command.

---

My suggestion is to use an environment variable. So in your `.env` file you can have:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
```

And in your `config/session.php` file you can have:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),
```

You can safely use the `env` helper method as it has no special dependencies.

---

If you really want to use the dynamic approach, you can set the cookie domain via a conditional assignment that only sets the cookie domain using `url` if the application is not running in console mode. So having this will do the trick:

```
'domain' => app()->runningInConsole() ? null : parse_url(url(''), PHP_URL_HOST),
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make the url dynamic? Right now I created a function that will remove the http:// part from the url(''). Even using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is resulting in an error.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution. Since you said you've created a function to remove the `http://` part from the URL, the solution also shows how you can use the native [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.parse-url.php) function to extract the domain from an URL, so there's no need for additional functions :).